# Discretizing over the area of an ellipse given bounds

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, ellipse, discretization

The problem is I have a center `(x,y)` and some standard deviations `sigma_{x1}` and `sigma_{x2}`, together I can use these to plot a Gaussian 3-sigma confidence interval of the center `(x,y)`

I need to discretize over this ellipsoid such that I can evaluate the expected value of a function as `f(x,y)*p(x,y)` but I am not sure how to generate the `x` and `y` "mesh". I'm not sure if mesh is the correct terminology here.

If this were a square instead the answer would be applying `np.linspace(start=min, stop=max)` for some arbitrary min/max value for `x` and `y`. I am not entirely sure how to proceed for non-rectangular shapes?  My thought process at first was to generate a rectangular region around and then select points for which solving the [ellipse equation](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/76457/check-if-a-point-is-within-an-ellipse) returns something <=1 but I figure this is not the most efficient way to implement this.

Note: Currently using python 3.6.9 and numpy 1.19.4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you can do it much more efficiently than with the approach you already proposed. To make a grid you can use

```
x, y = np.mgrid[minx:maxx:step*1j, miny:maxy:step*1j]
```

Here `mgrid` is basically a multidimensional version of `np.linspace`.

Then you just need to discard values outside of your ellipse and retain the ones inside. This is easiest by "masking" using logical indexing:

```
mask = x**2 + y**2 < 1  # replace unit circle equation with ellipse equation
x, y = x[mask], y[mask]
```

Then you can evaluate your expected value using

```
ev = (f(x,y) * p(x, y)).sum()
```

(assuming both `f` and `p` can deal with vectors as inputs).

Comment: Thanks for all the tips! If nothing else it'll be more efficient in that I won't be using for loops more or less.